# Iphone "Device" memory leaks

Tags: iphone, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks

After running the xcode-> run with instrument -> leaks,
After going over the Simulator with a fine-tooth-comb, and (Simulator) Instruments -> leaks shows ZERO. But When I run the actual device, I get a list of of about 100+ items,

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
GeneralBlock-64 9   < multiple >    576 UIKit   GetContextStack
GeneralBlock-16 7   < multiple >    112 WebCore WebThreadCurrentContext
UIControlTargetAction   5   < multiple >    160 UIKit   -[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]
__NSArrayM  5   < multiple >    160 UIKit   -[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]
UIButton    5   < multiple >    720
```

Blah, Blah, Blah..

I read some-where about someone mentioning that if you create any threads, they have to be on the Main thread?  (WTF? that doesn't make any sense).

Yes, my application uses threads, but only to render `UIAlertViews` and they are all sandwiched between `[pool autorelease]` and `[pool release]`, there are ZERO unreleased `NSStrings`, buttons, widgets. Everything that gets allocated, copied, retained, gets released.

Anyone know about this Thread that get pool'd, causing crazy memory leaks?

Thanks in advance!

****** 25 May 2011 (11:35am JPN time) ***********************

Ok, I think I've manage to determine the cause of my memory woes... It's those fricken 'AutoRelease UITableViewCells'... They are NOT getting released, in a timely enough manner, before they cause my app to crash... I just looked through the AppleTableViewCell API and I didn't see anything about determining if a 'TV-Cell' is actually 'IN-USE.' Because my app will only hold 30 cells per page, but these auto release cells, kept on growing until I got the memory low warning (124 TV cells). Anyone...? Know how I can SAFELY Release these...? –

I've tried using regular 'Alloc', and releasing the one's that come straight out of the De-queue,(just so I know that at least a good number were getting released, but as expected, it didn't like that.. So I wonder, if it's possible to do something like in ViewDidUnload() for(cells in queue) [release cell] and rifle through the whole queue, to make sure they were all killed (of course I wouldn't use auto-release) Any Ideas, Any IOS Guru..? Thank You in Advance! – ChinaSailor 40 secs ago edit

Comment: One leaked object can cause many others to be leaked...

Comment: You shouldn't (read: don't need to) be using NSAutoreleasePools in most Cocoa code (unless you are implementing an asynchronous NSOperation or something of that nature).  I would be interested to see an example of how you are using NSAutoreleasePools in your code.

Comment: What you probably read is that you should only update UI (UIKit) elements on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Instruments with Zombies enabled so your leaked objects are available to inspect after they've leaked away.

Just having the NSZombieEnabled in the environment variables isn't enough. YOu have to turn it on in Instrument too. This tutorial helped me; [How To Debug Memory Leaks with XCode and Instruments Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).

Comment: Ok, not exactly sure about how to specifically enable NSZombies in the instrument, because the xcode I am using (Version 3.2.5) had Zombies enabled, and according to a tutorial I saw online about setting instruments with zombies, it's completely missing those options, under, "target"... It doesn't show, like what-ever version the tutorial had... It gives me several options to "Ignore" allocations starting with 'NS', but no NSZombieEnable like the web site... thanks...

Answer (score 1):

> I read some-where about someone mentioning that if you create any threads, they have to be on the Main thread? (WTF? that doesn't make any sense).

false - you can create a thread from a thread other than the main thread. agreed, that makes no sense.

> Yes, my application uses threads, but only to render UIAlertViews and they are all sandwiched between [pool autorelease] and [pool release], there are ZERO unreleased NSStrings, buttons, widgets. Everything that gets allocated, copied, retained, gets released.
>
> Anyone know about this Thread that get pool'd, causing crazy memory leaks?

create and manipulate UIKit objects on the main thread. period.

good luck!

(although that answer may not be the exact reason for all/any of your issues -- it is a good candidate and fatal flaw from the description given)

Comment: "create and manipulate UIKit objects on the main thread. period."  Ok, have Never heard anything in regard to this, other than you obviously do not want to have collisions with threads trying to access the same memory at the same time, if that's what you mean... I have read, don't spawn any threads to do MAIN Graphics manipulations, because apple handles that on main thread, but that is only because of thread collisions, not because of dangling pointers and unreleased memory... Or is it...? Thanks!

Comment: it's because UIKit (and AppKit) are not designed to be thread-safe. they are designed to be manipulated from the main thread only. the only portable assumption you can make about these objects is that they should be created and manipulated exclusively from the main thread. although there are technically a few things you can get away with beyond that - don't bother with them for now, and stick to manipulating and creating from the main thread alone. you're welcome.

Comment: i'd just write something like: `assert([NSThread isMainThread]);`

Comment: Ok, I think I've manage to determine the cause of my memory woes... It's those fricken 'AutoRelease UITableViewCells'... They are NOT getting released, in a timely enough manner, before they cause my app to crash... I just looked through the AppleTableViewCell API and I didn't see anything about determining if a 'TV-Cell' is actually 'IN-USE.' Because my app will only hold 30 cells per page, but these auto release cells, kept on growing until I got the memory low warning (124 TV cells). Anyone...? Know how I can SAFELY Release these...?

Comment: I've tried using regular 'Alloc', and releasing the one's that come straight out of the De-queue,(just so I know that at least a good number were getting released, but as expected, it didn't like that.. So I wonder, if it's possible to do something like in ViewDidUnload() for(cells in queue) [release cell] and rifle through the whole queue, to make sure they were all killed (of course I wouldn't use auto-release)  Any Ideas, Any IOS Guru..? Thank You in Advance!

Comment: you should reuse your cells. the implementation already exists for reuse (the hard part is done); you just need to teach your cells to reuse themselves. the table should own the cells - you just populate them. the table will limit the number of cells it uses to (est.) 1 to 2 times as many as it can fit in its view. the delegate method you use as a starting point for your reuse implementation is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. the table's implementation manages cells well enough when reuse is supported.

Comment: Yes, I do reuse Cells, to the maximum extent possible... But I am using very complex, multi-imaged/buttoned cells, so I have like 3 types of cells that get reused, otherwise, you end up with duplicate cells, having the same picture or buttons, that isn't supposed to exist on the other cells.. Short answer, YES I reuse, but the Auto-release, isn't cleaning up, key words here, 'Fast Enough.' So at about 120+ 'Auto-Release Cells,' it very quickly crashes the app...

Comment: Thank you, Justin... Should I perhaps, like try having a duplicate, identical TableView Controller, that gets swapped with the other, so that, every page load, the whole TableViewController get's killed & deallocated..? Any Ideas..? Thank!

Comment: assuming you rarely use `autorelease`: the simplest means to reduce the level of autoreleased objects is to explicitly create your own `NSAutoreleasePool`s. creating them is very fast, and they may reduce your peak memory significantly. unfortunately, there is no instrument template that i know of that allows you to measure autorelease sizes or weights - i wrote my own autorelease pool for this diagnosis (size/count). good luck.

Comment: i would not recommend swapping/constructing/replacing/destroying tables all over the place - that sounds like desperation. try the explicit inner autorelease pool i suggested.

Comment: Great... Yes, I have been thinking about that... Any Suggestions, where I might implement it..? Make it a Member of that class? and init it in the viewDidLoad..? And release it in the Dealloc..? or ViewDid Unload..? (BTW: just doing some simple arithmetic, about (24 pages x 30 cells) were loaded and only about 120 cells pooled, so that looks like about an 83% re-use rate, if my math is correct..) Thank You !

Comment: you should really use instruments to determine what the allocations are. maybe you can concrete copy, cache, or reuse what is causing the memory growth.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` would be good, but they only target the beginning and end of the table's lifetime. start with your own code, where you create and configure your cells, where you load your images, where you perform mass cell operations/configurations/updates. i can't help you much here because i don't know your program - only you and instruments know it. your last comment pointed out a potential issue: if you have offscreen tables, destroy them when they go offscreen and rebuild them when the user navigates back to them (there is a bit of balancing here).

Comment: Ok... Thanks... Actually, it's quite simple, but a tabBarController, holds three views, one of them being the TV-Controller-View and the page will get re-load by a button on a navBar, so the whole TabBarController basically gets released, and reloaded with the new content (of cells).  Thanks again, I will try all of your suggestions.

Comment: Yea... Basically a No-Go with the AutoReleasePool, unless the TV or Pool is subclassed or something along those lines... member status means nothing... " *** attempt to pop an unknown autorelease pool (0x905e00)" and *** -[CFSet countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x71e2ef0 and Crash...

Comment: Yea... I went back again and redefined, in a much less stringent way the way cells are re-used, and it still uses a hell of a lot of cells, and a fair amount of those are getting mangled, with buttons that shouldn't be there or pictures from other cells being pasted onto the top of text of cells... mmmmm..... apple...

Comment: there's a very specific way to use autorelease pools. basically, it has a scope, similar to c scopes. when the pool is destroyed all the autoreleased objects that were collected while the pool was on the top of the autorelease pool stack will be messaged `release` -- it's predictable, and should never lead to a zombie or mystery crash.  (cont)

Comment: assuming that is your problem (and not a simple memory management error nearby): you probably did not explicitly retain+autorelease cycle an object that is intended to live beyond the pool's lifetime. to do this: retain the autoreleased object before the pool is destroyed, then autorelease it after the inner pool is destroyed

Comment: but the pool *probably* doesn't matter much here - you *probably* should be looking at tearing down views which are not visible (can't be too sure with the information i have).

Comment: Ok, as far as the 'AutoReleasePool' at first I defined it as a class member with @property (retain) but of course, it won't compile like that, so used 'assign.' I am a not quite sure what you mean by 'inner pool', I should use 2 autoReleasePool's, with one nested..? And use a retain statement some-where before the actual TableView gets deallocated..?  I am still a little unsure where or WTF apple is doing with these cells, because this TableViewController gets destroyed & re-allocated with every load, which, to me that means, what-ever objects (i.e.. Cells) it had should be destroyed as well

Comment: (Cont..) But the Cells do not go anywhere... And Matter of fact, I can watch exactly how many TVCells it Released during about 20 pages of content. it was like 2.... A whole 2 cells got released by apple's auto-release mechanism, while they were at 120 cells and counting. The TV Controller I have only loads 30 cells per page, so I am a bit confused why it holds onto so many cells, for so long. It was actually going fairly well, when I was 'Deque-ing' the re-usable cells and immediately releasing, then allocating them manually. But of course, all it took was one 'release message' to arrive late

Comment: autorelease pools are set up like stacks on the thread they operate on - it is very unusual to add one as an ivar of an objc class. you *typically* create them in a function (or method or...) and destroy them when the scope exits (e.g. you create it as the first thing in a function, then drain it as the last thing before your function returns. maybe you should ask a colleague/senior to review your code and help you isolate the problems? we're not making much progress using these message boxes.

Comment: the thread's autorelease pool is fully drained when the thread exits, or when the run loop's finished its cycle. they operate as a stack, and have short lives. the pool does not wait a long time to drain (e.g. if on the main thread, one full autorelease stack is created and destroyed at least as often as the screen updates).

Comment: you're welcome. *BTW: are there any weird side effects to using UITextViews in Custom cells...?*: nothing that immediately comes to mind... maybe a new question here @SO would be a good idea?

Comment: "nothing that immediately comes to mind... maybe a new question here @SO would be a good idea?"  Same question, I meant in Regard to causing memory problems, Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI: "An autorelease pool should always be drained in the same context (invocation of a method or function, or body of a loop) in which it was created" (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047)

Comment: i know this; i explicitly create them often. i attempted to explain that to you when i detailed stacks and scopes in relation to autorelease pools.

Comment: Sorry, I am only a Linux programmer in sheep's clothing. Obj-C is Obj-C, Not C, C++ or anything else (maybe smalltalk)... And never the twain shall meet...

Comment: Sincerely, Thank you for your attempt at helping, although I am not sure, either you don't entirely understand the question or the exact details of what you are trying to explain, it's ok, if you don't know or understand the details to just say so... In Theory everything is perfect, but until you actually do it, you don't know exactly what will happen.